# ByteArrayInputStream vs own class

Tags: java

I was wondering whether is [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) class from java.io package good to be used? Or if it were to be compared with own class by using byte arrays such as:

```
private int pos = 0;
private final byte[] total;

public Reader(final byte[] total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public int read() {
    return ((int) total[pos++]) & 0xFF;
}
```

The bytes isn't obtained from a file, it was supposed to be a server receiving bytes/packets. The function does the same as the one in ByteArrayInputStream. I was curious if ByteArrayInputStream class would be used, does it increase the amount of bytes placed into the java's memory? But basically, in performance wise, which would be more recommended?

Thank you.

EDIT* I think I've got my answer, i was wondering what's the difference between mark() and skip() method in it? The function seemed to be the same, just that one changes the position, and one reads bytes to skip them.

Comment: a class maintained for years vs a class written a saturday morning...

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `read()` is surprisingly similar to the one in `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
public synchronized int read() {
return (pos < count) ? (buf[pos++] & 0xff) : -1;
}
```

Only extra overhead comes from `synchronized`, which I would consider negligible. `ByteArrayInputStream` is basically a thin wrapper around `byte[]`. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

By all means, if Java provides a class with a specific functionality, use that class and spend your own time better. ByteArrayInputStream will store two more integers compared to your code, so the difference is negligible. Its read method is essentially the same as the one you have written.

Performancewise, you will get much better results by reading more than one byte at a time. Again, ByteArrayinputStream provides this functionality for you.

Comment: Alright, by the way what's the difference between mark() and skip() in it? Oh and, as you've said, reading more then one byte at a time, wouldn't that use the System.arraycopy method in java? I heard that it seemed to be slow...

Comment: Skip allows you to skip a number of bytes so they are not read while mark allows you to jump a number of bytes back in the stream at a later point.

Comment: Reading data into a buffer will probably use System.arraycopy. That is much faster than reading and copying one byte at a time. It is very fast since it can rely on memory operations in the OS (it is essentially equivalent to the `memcpy` function of the standard C library). That is the whole point of having the System.arraycopy method available.

Answer (score 2):

I'd usually look at using an existing `java.io` class.

1. It'll be well debugged
2. It'll save you development time
3. It'll implement the appropriate interfaces etc. to interact well with other classes
4. Other developers will be familiar with it

I really wouldn't reinvent the wheel unless there's a *compelling* reason to do so.